# Select children when parent selected in TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-mptt

I'm using django-mptt in my project. Form is:

```
class UserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
      category = TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        queryset=NewsCategory.objects.all(), label=u"category",  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
      class Meta:
        model = UserSettings
```

[image]

I want to select children when parent selected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add custom JS code to your form or widget. Just like in docs on [Form Media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/media/)

For widget (custom):

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('pretty.css',)
        }
        js = ('animations.js', 'actions.js')
```

Or for entire form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    date = DateField(widget=CalendarWidget)
    name = CharField(max_length=40, widget=OtherWidget)

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('layout.css',)
        }
```

Comment: many thanks. I know form media but how can I do this for mpt.

Comment: Then I misunderstood you. Where do you want to select children on the server or on the client?